# THREE.js - Rotate the camera just like trackball controls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using Trackball controls in a scene and I want to implement a function to rotate the camera just like the way dragging the mouse in the canvas does it. How can I accomplish something like that? I've been looking the code of the Trackball control module, but I can't find something to start.

EDIT: I've been looking several pages, the THREE documentation and whatnot, but still can't reproduce the Trackball style rotation. I've been using quaternions too but they can't reproduce the behavior(or I'm missing something, most probably). Any help?

EDIT 2 : What I'm looking for is a way to do something like this:

```
function rotateCam(angle) { // code }

var angle = 0.01; //some value
rotateCam(angle);
$('#button').addEventListener('mousedown', function() { rotateCam(angle); } );
```

Where `button` is an HTML element representing a button.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to click the trackball button and then move the trackball around to get the same effect?

Comment: I need to do it without the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that the Trackball controls, apart of rotate via quaternion, do a zoom to correct some distances. I tried to read the code, and got this:

```
function rotate(L) {
    var vector = controls.target.clone();
    var l = (new THREE.Vector3()).subVectors(camera.position, vector).length();
    var up = camera.up.clone();
    var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

    // Zoom correction
    camera.translateZ(L - l);

    quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(up, 0.015);
    camera.position.applyQuaternion(quaternion);
    camera.lookAt(vector);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Works like a charm...hope someone find this useful too. ;)

Comment: the parameter with 1 char L decreases the readability of the code

Comment: What is L? (baby don't hurt me, don't hurt me, no more). Is it how much you want to rotate it? The absolute new angle maybe?

Comment: i don't condemn cause in the end what is important is: working software. but in my personal point of view readability isn't matter of taste...

Answer (score 1):

```
function cameraRotate(distance, angle){

            camera.position.x = distance * Math.cos( angle );
            camera.position.z = distance * Math.sin( angle );

}
```

This would rotate your camera at the specified distance and angle around the scene. If you want a smooth rotation you could call this with a small angle increase from the animate-loop, depending on input for example.

Comment: What if the camera is not looking at (0, 0, 0)? And if it's rotated around X, Y and/or Z? Those are cases that are addressed in the TrackballControls rotation.

Comment: I'm still awarding you the bounty, because you were the only one interested after all. Thanks mate ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the right way I think...I did this:

```
function rotate() {
    if (this.showCase) {
        var vector = controls.target.clone(); // controls is a TrackballControls
        var up = camera.up.clone();
        var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
        quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(up, 0.015);
        camera.position.applyQuaternion(quaternion);
        camera.lookAt(vector);
        renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    }
},
```

Still, it doesn't look right right like the TrackballControls rotation.